Difference between words for "abolish/repeal/do away with"
I have had a hard time distinguishing words I've found that can mean "abolish", because especially in the context of abolishing something like a political system some of them seem to have significant overlap.
From my dictionaries this is my understanding of these words:

廃止
Used in the context of repealing things like systems, can also mean practices or technologies fall into disuse.
廃絶
Seems to be used more for physical objects falling into disuse and disappearing like old houses, seems also to be the most common for expressing things like advocating for nuclear disarmament.
撤廃
Also seems to be used in the context of repealing things like systems, but is more common than 廃止 to speak of advocating for repealing some system.
廃する
Outside of additional meanings of "dethrone" or "abandon [one's studies, etc]", it seems to be used almost exactly like 廃止する.
打破
Less like "abolish" and more like "break down", more commonly used for breaking down an enemy (stopping them), but I did see this usage in my dictionary:
階級差別の打破　the abolition of class distinctions.

I can sense differences here, but some of these words seem very similar, so I can imagine times where when one wants to use something like "abolish" or "repeal" or "do away with" that there could be confusion.


廃止 is a neutral term meaning discontinuation of a law, rule, system, periodic event, etc. It doesn't say anything about whether the discontinued thing was good or bad. For example, you can say 300年続いた祭りが今年で廃止になってしまった.
撤廃 is used with rules or systems, and has a connotation that the discontinued/withdrawn rule was fairly detrimental.
廃絶 is even stronger and has a connotation of "(abolish and) exterminate". It refers to a complete and permanent elimination of something considered truly evil, such as slavery or nuclear weapons. This is fine in certain types of campaigns, but shouldn't be used lightly.
廃する sounds literary and dramatic when compared to 廃止する. When in doubt, 廃止する is safer in ordinary business settings.
打破 is typically used with 困難, 強敵, 現状, etc.

